Getting error while running the collection thriough CLI my .json file is present under folder and using command run bru --output result.junit
I am inside same folder in which my collection-name.json file is present
bru run  --output results.junit
Getting error message as
(node:27337) [DEP0040] DeprecationWarning: The punycode module is deprecated. Please use a userland alternative instead.
(Use node --trace-deprecation ... to show where the warning was created)
You can run only at the root of a collection
bru run  --output results.junit
but getting error message
even tried this
bru run  collection-name.json --output results.junit
